# why android layouts from SDK are incorrectly shown when viewed from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to see how `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` looks like, so I go to the SDK attached to the project and locate this layout there:

[image]

However, when I double click the resource, I see the corrupted file in the editor:

[image]

Why so?

Comment: This isn't happening on my machine. I see a perfectly formatted layout file with no weird characters. How did you obtain the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `External Libraries` node, don't expand `android.jar`. Instead, go below that and expand the `res` node.
[image]